# Careers Reading - 'add an article or blog post you’ve read' is broken

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

I'm trying to add some blog articles to my **Reading** section on the Careers site but nothing happens when I click the button.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to **Edit Profile** page at [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).
2. Scroll down to "**Reading**" section and click on "*add an article or blog post you’ve read*".
3. Enter a URL of an online article into the box and click the "*get article*" button.
4. Absolutely nothing happens.

**Result**:  The URL stays in the box and there are no error messages, nothing loads onto the page... absolutely nothing happens.  I've tried in Safari and Firefox and I've tried different URL's from various domains.

---

**EDIT**:

I tried Chrome and it finally worked.  So it seems to be an issue of not failing gracefully when the browser is not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to simply be an issue of browser compatibility or it simply doesn't support slightly out of date browsers.  (Safari version 4)

When I tried Chrome, the problem went away and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With IE8, the problem is in the embedded script on the page http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/article/reading/XYZ, line 285:

```
Careers.import.init();
```